# Sitecore page editor - how to extend page editor item editing panel

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

Need to add "publish" feature to the page editor, item editing section. (Under the "More" section would be ideal). How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to create a command class. The simplest version would be:

```c#
using System;
using Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands;
using Sitecore.Shell.Framework;
using Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands;

namespace my.assembly.namespace
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Publish : WebEditCommand
    {
        public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
        {
            if (context.Items.Length != 1)
                return;
            Items.Publish(context.Items[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Register new command in `Sitecore.config` (or `Commands.config`):

```c#
<configuration> 
  <sitecore>
    <commands>
      <command name="my:publish" type="my.assembly.namespace.Publish,my.assembly"/> 
    </commands>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Then:

1. Login to **Sitecore Desktop**
2. Switch database to **core**
3. Duplicate `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Common Field Buttons/Edit related item`
4. Rename new item to `Publish related item`
5. Set `Click` property of this item to `my:publish`
6. Change other properties of the item (`Header`, `Icon`, `Tooltip`)
7. Switch database back to **master**
8. Open **Page Editor** and test the new command (it should open the standard publishing popup with the related item **ID** as a parameter in URL).

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve it without any code change.

```
<command name="webedit:publish"  type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.PublishItem,Sitecore.Kernel" />
```

Add the above entry in Commands.config file. This file is available in include folder.

1. Login to Sitecore Desktop
2. Switch database to core
3. Duplicate /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Common Field Buttons/Edit related item
4. Rename new item to Publish related item
5. Set Click property of this item to chrome:common:edititem({command:"webedit:publish"})
6. Switch database back to master
7. Open Page Editor and test the new command (it should open the standard publishing popup with the related item ID as a parameter in URL).

Thanks

Fenil