# Sitecore Page editor Publish specific item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms, page-editor

I created **sitecore HTML Content control** based on sitecore datasource; which can be used for Multivariate Testing and Personalization. Everything working fine if change some content or image and saving it in page editor.

Things started not working when i publish the item in Page editor;i don't have specific option to publish that control rather clicking on publish button with disabling(un-checking) publish sub items.Result in the publish information "Items Skipped 2","Items updated 0"

Similar topic was discussed  in below link.
[Sitecore Page Editor Publishing items related to content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348988/sitecore-page-editor-publishing-items-related-to-content)

[Sitecore page editor - how to extend page editor item editing panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350587/sitecore-page-editor-how-to-extend-page-editor-item-editing-panel/18351584#18351584)

The solution suggested in that post is to create a custom button to publish.

Is there any any sitecore default feature for this to publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have raised a sitecore support ticket. Looks like this feature is not yet available in Sitecore. Hopefully we see this in near feature.

Response from Sitecore Support:

*"I have registered a feature request for the product so it can be considered for future implementation. We will inform you when there are any updates regarding your request.
You can use the approach suggested in article that you have found - [Sitecore page editor - how to extend page editor item editing panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350587/sitecore-page-editor-how-to-extend-page-editor-item-editing-panel/18351584#18351584)."*